# Laravel 5 returns JSON instead of object on belongsTo() relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have installed Laravel framework v5.3.2 and [dimsav/aravel-translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) package v6.0.1. I'm having problem with getting data from belongsTo() relationship (parent) on same model.

**Category.php** model

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public $translatedAttributes = [
        'name', 'slug', 'description'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Method for getting list of all categories:

```
$categoryModel = new Category;
$categories = $categoryModel->with('category.translations')->get();
```

When I print name attribute in view, Laravel throws exception: "Trying to get property of non-object".

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    Name: <?php echo $category->category->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But when I try to get value as array it works:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    Name: <?php echo $category->category['name']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

One more thing, when i try to **var_dump($category->category)** inside foreach I get this:

```
object(App\Model\Category)[221]...
```

Results of **dd($category)** in view inside foreach:

```
Category {#231 ▼
    #table: "category"
    +translatedAttributes: array:4 [▶]
    +timestamps: false
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    #attributes: array:3 [▶]
    #original: array:3 [▶]
    #relations: array:2 [▼
        "category" => Category {#220 ▶}
        "translations" => Collection {#228 ▶}
    ]
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

So the object exists but Laravel does not show it properly when i try accessing the attribute directly. Anyone knows where the problem is? Is it in Laravel or maybe in laravel-translatable package?

Answer (score 0):

This code returns collection of objects:

```
$categoryModel->with('category')->get();
```

But you're trying to use it as object and that's why you're getting the error.

You need to iterate over collection to use objects in it, so try something like this:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->category->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok, please update your question (or post somewhere esle) with result of `{{ dd($category) }}` inside foreach loop please.

Comment: Updated question. Hmm strange, category relation is null. Why if i tried to eager load parent category?

Comment: Maybe first category in a collection doesn't have any categories or something?

Comment: LOL thats true ;) edit getter of categories to: $categories = $this->categoryModel->with('category.translations')->get(); to get translations for parent category. But still, no clue why it is not working. dd() or debug() tree is OK, i see category -> relations -> category -> relations -> translations...

Comment: I don't data structure, so can't tell how to do it. But maybe each category has collection of categories? And/or maybe each sub category (parent category?) has view translations? In this case you should iterate each collection with `foreach` inside main `foreach` loop. Or use `first()` to get object from a collection if it has just one onject in it.

Comment: I only know that it works when accessing as array - $category->category['name'], and does not work when trying to access via property - $category->category->name

Comment: Figured it out, your 2nd comment answers it: "Maybe first category in a collection doesn't have any categories or something?". So this works - <?php echo ($category->category ? $category->category->name : '') ?> Thanks!